# Why does Intellisense in vscode not recognize .html5 files?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Unfortunately Intellisense does not recognize .html5 files in vscode (visual studio code). So it doesn't show me any code completion. Does anyone know where to set this up correctly? Thxs...

Comment: Look at file associations.

Comment: that is a `settings.json` option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw that in this case a php file was saved under .html5, otherwise I think vscode would recognize the correct language. So I changed the language in the right bottom corner only for this file.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file